# How to open a new tab from BHO?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho, ieaddon

I would like to open a new tab from my BHO done in C#. Process.Start(u) opens a new window, not a tab, and call the default browsers, which might not be IE.

I want to open the new tab to prompt the user to download and install the latest version of the BHO.

Comment: I know IE7 doesn't support this. Is there a specific version of IE you are targeting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this from a BHO is to use `IWebBrowser2::Navigate2()` ([doc link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa752134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and pass `navOpenInNewTab` ([doc link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa768360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

The interop [exists at pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IWebBrowser2.html), so you can probably start with that.

You can get the IWebBrowser2 pointer from your site by following these steps:

1. QueryInterface() your site for IID_IServiceProvider.
2. QueryService() the IServiceProvider for SID_STopLevelBrowser, IID_IServiceProvider.
3. QueryService() the top level IServiceProvider for SID_SWebBrowserApp, IID_IWebBrowser2.

...but I don't know how to do it in C#.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize the TargetFrameName can be used to open a new tab: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491275%28v=vs.90%29.aspx it is a "native" C# method, no need to do pinvoke

Comment: By targeting _blank or some such, you may get a new tab, but the user can configure that behavior to some extent, so it may be a new window.