# Open URL in new tab (Internet Explorer)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am developing custom toolbar (added one toolbar button) for Internet Explorer.
I written the code in COM. 
When the user clicks my toolbar button I need to open a URL in new tab. I have written a navigate function as below. This function fails to open URL in new tab and always returns E_FAIL.

```
HRESUTL Navigate(CString csUrl) {
ATLASSERT(0 <= Url.Length());
ATLASSERT(m_pWebBrowser);

if (m_pWebBrowser == NULL) {
    return E_FAIL;
}

m_pWebBrowser->Stop();

VARIANT vUrl;
vUrl.vt = VT_BSTR;
vUrl.bstrVal = csUrl.AllocSysString();

VARIANT vFlag;
vFlag.vt = VT_I4;
vFlag.intVal = navOpenInNewTab;

VARIANT vEmpty;
VariantInit(&vEmpty);

HRESULT hr = m_pWebBrowser->Navigate2(&vUrl, &vFlag, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);

if (hr == E_OUTOFMEMORY)
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Out of Memory.", L"Navigate", MB_OK);
else if (hr == E_INVALIDARG || hr == E_FAIL)
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to navigate.", L"Navigate", MB_OK);

::SysFreeString(vUrl.bstrVal);

ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

return hr; }
```

What parameters I need to pass for "Navigate2" method to open the URL in new tab.

Please suggest me on this.

Regards,
Santhosh

Comment: You should call Navigate on the Top Level Browser object (SID_STopLevelBrowser). A similar question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370540/how-to-open-a-new-tab-from-bho/9382742#9382742).

Comment: Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa768360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried with Top Level Browser Object. Still the same issue. I am using IE 8.

Comment: @Noseratio I tried as you suggested by getting Top Level Browser Object. But still the same issue. I'm using IE 8.

Comment: Is your extension a BHO? How do you obtain `m_pWebBrowser` in the first place? Show some more code.

Comment: I am adding my SetSite function.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating toolbar for IE.

This is my SetSite method

```
HRESULT CMyClass::SetupBrowser(IUnknown* pUnkSite) {
ATLASSERT(pUnkSite);
HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

IOleCommandTarget* pCmdTarget = NULL;   
if (SUCCEEDED(pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IOleCommandTarget,
                        (LPVOID*)&pCmdTarget)) && NULL != pCmdTarget) {
    IServiceProvider* pSP = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pCmdTarget->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider,
                                (LPVOID*)&pSP)) && NULL != pSP) {
        CComPtr<IServiceProvider> child_provider;
        hr = pSP->QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser,
                               IID_IServiceProvider,
                               reinterpret_cast<void**>(&child_provider));
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = child_provider->QueryService(SID_SWebBrowserApp,
                                              IID_IWebBrowser2,
                                              reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pWebBrowser));
        }

        /*hr = pSP->QueryService(SID_SWebBrowserApp,
                                IID_IWebBrowser2,
                                (LPVOID*)&m_pWebBrowser);*/
        ATLASSERT(m_pWebBrowser);
        pSP->Release();
    }
    pCmdTarget->Release();
}

m_ReflectWnd.GetToolBar().SetBrowser(m_pWebBrowser);

return hr; }
```

Comment: It'd be more appropriate to edit your original question and add the code there. Anyway, the code seems to be correct, I'm unable to spot a problem. What if you use `navOpenInNewWindow`, does it open a new window or still return `E_FAIL`?

Comment: sorry for that. Yes If I use navOpenInNewWindow it returns E_FAIL.

Comment: Can I use a javascript to open the URL in new tab and can it be executed from my native code? Just a thought.

Comment: You could, by injecting some JavaScript into the current document (through `IWebBrowser2::get_Document`). Before you go that route, could you check the value of `IWebBrowser2::get_FullName`, does it have "iexplore.exe" in it? Also, have you tried your IE extension on a different machine?

Comment: get_FullName returns "C:\ProgramFile\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe". I tried in different system too, the result is same. To inform you that I tried with one more approach by creating COM object for CLSID_InternetExplorer, query for IWebBrowser2  like hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL,  CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&m_spWebBrowser); call m_spWebBrowser->Navigate2() twice one with navOpenInNewTab enabled opens a new window then creates tab.Ideally this is not my requirement(where it opens a new window).

Comment: I don't really know why this is happening, but I'd try one more thing.  Defer the navigation by posting a custom message to your own window (with `PostMessage`). Handle the message and call `Navigate2` there.

Comment: @ Noseratio, Thanks for your help. To resolve this issue I used ShellExecute to navigate the URL.