# In IE Browser Helper Object, force IWebBrowser2.Navigate2 to open new tab in a new window

Tags: window, bho

When working on an IE Browser Helper Object, I observed that when calling `IWebBrowser2::Navigate2` method with flag `navOpenInNewWindow`, if its called in BHO's `IObjectWithSite::SetSite` method, the new tab is open in a new IE window; but if its called in BHO's `DWebBrowserEvents2::OnDocumentComplete` event handler, the new tab is open in current IE window.

I'd like to open new tab in new window in BHO's DWebBrowserEvents2.OnDocumentComplete event handler. I tried several ways, including assign "_blank" target frame name, and tried IHTMLDocument2.open method (following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925279/iwebbrowser2-how-to-force-links-to-open-in-new-window)). But no way works. Anyone can help me to enable it, or anyone can tell me whether its possible to do it? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab from BHO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370540/how-to-open-a-new-tab-from-bho)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the open method of IHTMLWindow2.

```
CComPtr<IHTMLWindow2> auth_win;
active_win->open(url,L"_blank",L"fullscreen=yes, toolbar=yes",false,&auth_win);
```

Comment: I've already tried it. But unfortunately, the result is same.